# Incorporation of multiprocessing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, multiprocessing

I tried creating a simple game using the pygame module in python. It's a two player game, so it involves getting simultaneous inputs or in other words, events, in the same pygame screen. I tried using multithreading, that is, by running two threads that share a pygame screen, but it didn't work due to the GIL. So, when I tried using multiprocessing instead, I faced a problem in that I couldn't share the same pygame screen. So is there a way to create a pool that has the pygame screen, like there is for sequences? If not, is there any other, perhaps better method to approach my problem? Any answers will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't need either multi-threading and much less multi-processing there.

What do you mean by "it didn't work due to the GIL"? Did you get any error message when trying to do multi-threaded?

It *is* possible to create a naive multi-threading design that could facilitate updating objects controlled by different players, but some care would have to be taken anyway. The GIL should only impact you that you really would have no benefit like using more than 1 core in your application, but won't give you any errors.

As for using multi-processing, the secondary process would not be able to use the screen Surface anyway, and passing surfaces (images) across process is mostly not worth it (if it is feasible at all).

> I meant that when I pressed a button, only one of the threads detected
>   key down. I did not get any errors. It is due to GIL right? I'm sorry
>   if I'm wrong.

No  - this does not have to do with the GIL in any way -- it has to do with the pygame event API not having being designed to work with threads.

There are two ways of dealing with key-presses in Pygame: either checking for `KEYDOWN` events, or calling `pygame.key.get_pressed`. I usually prefer the second due to it not depending on key auto-repeating settings at the OS or BIOS level (unless, of course, it is an action that is to be executed just once, and not while a key is pressed).

Anyway, in any pygame related project, you should check for pygame events (key presses included) in a single place in your code, and on the same thread. Once you have the information you need from the "outside world", you can set your internal variables as you want.

But, since you don't offer any code, the most direct fix I can suggest to your multi-threaded code is to use [`get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) instead of checking for events: it will likely work from both threads.  (the multi-processing code would be much more complicated than that).

Comment: I meant that when I pressed a button, only one of the threads detected key down. I did not get any errors. It is due to GIL right? I'm sorry if I'm wrong. Also, can you please suggest a better way to accept simultaneous inputs then. Like the python alternative for kbhit() in C++? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that